# how to use pydev in sublime using sublimeREPL

Tags: python, pydev, remote-debugging, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I was wondering if it is possible to use PyDev in Sublime. Because it has all this great debugging features that are missing in Sublime.
I know that it hasn't been implemented but I think with a few tricks we can use PyDev in Sublime.

There is also SublimeREPL plugin which allows you to run an interpreter inside Sublime.
https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

Moreover, there is this remote debugging ability from PyDev documented here which I think we can take advantage of.
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Any brainstorming on how to do this would be appreciated because I think it is at least theoretically possible with some hacks!

P.S. I am using Sublime Text 3 and Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit. Also, I have Eclipse and Pydev installed.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make an entire package containing a build system, syntax support etc... where to start is difficult for me to say as I have never used pydev but the goal would surely be to mimic the IDE of pydev in sublime.

I am not aware of anything that enables remote debugging in sublime text so again this would have to be coded as part of your package.

You could perhaps start this package by specifically writing a list of all the features you would like to see in sublime, see if they exist on package control site https://packagecontrol.io/ if they do great install them no point repeating what someone else has done if it works towards your goals if not then add it to your list to begin creating your package.

These would be some good starting points on learning how to configure sublime text as well for me I tend to do it as I go along looking up what I need and building it whether it be a theme or a build system:

packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package

and

sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html

and

sublimetext.com/docs/3/

I use this personally on a unix system and it works well in respect of REPL:

github.com/spywhere/Terminality/ and is more configurable I think...

Sorry if it is not a specific answer as I have never used pydev its difficult for me to make the comparison and I am not sure from your question if you wanted full blown pydev in sublime text or only the features you mentioned?